# How do I install make?

Tags: make

```
/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl --all
ERROR: Using install-module.pl requires that you install "make".
```

I need to install make on my ubuntu on AWS EC2. How can I do that ?
I could finally install build-essential also successfully.

```
# make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Comment: Related, though currently also lacking an answer: [Bugzilla install-module.pl can't find “make” but it's installed and in my path](http://serverfault.com/questions/327620/bugzilla-install-module-pl-cant-find-make-but-its-installed-and-in-my-path)

Answer (score 5):

In this situation, *the `make` command is already installed.*

```
# make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

That means `make` *actually ran*, but failed because there is no file called `Makefile` in the current directory.

The problem here is that `perl` is not able to find `make` even though it is installed. As [ændrük commented](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161060/how-do-i-install-make?rq=1#comment196170_161060), this has been [asked on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/327620/bugzilla-install-module-pl-cant-find-make-but-its-installed-and-in-my-path). Since ændrük's comment, solutions have been posted there.

[According](https://serverfault.com/a/327668/99345) to [quanta](https://serverfault.com/users/59925/quanta), this can be fixed by running `perl -MCPAN -e shell` and then, at the `cpan>` menu, `install Math::Random::Secure`.

[According](https://serverfault.com/a/413283/99345) to [ocach](https://serverfault.com/users/100656/ochach), this can be fixed by running `cpan` followed by these two commands on the `cpan[n]` prompt:

> ```
> o conf make '/usr/bin/make' #or path to your make
> o conf commit
> ```

I tried ochach's way on my machine, and it *seemed* to work:

```
cpan[1]> o conf make '/usr/bin/make'
    make               [/usr/bin/make]
Please use 'o conf commit' to make the config permanent!


cpan[2]> o conf commit
commit: wrote '/home/ek/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm'
```

I recommend trying those techniques; it seems likely one of them will solve your problem.