# How do I install make?

Tags: software-installation, make

```
/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl --all
ERROR: Using install-module.pl requires that you install "make".
```

I need to install make on my ubuntu on AWS EC2. How can I do that ?
I could finally install build-essential also successfully.

```
# make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Comment: which ubuntu version do you use?

Comment: Version I am using is 11.04 (GNU/Linux 2.6.38-8-virtual x86_64)

Comment: just saw, that on my ubuntu 12.04 there is also a package `make`. probably `sudo apt-get install make` will work...

Comment: sudo apt-get install make
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package make is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'make' has no installation candidate

Comment: The `make` package definitely *should* be available; I have version 3.81-8.1ubuntu1 on my system. You might have a problem with your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, which defines where `apt-get` looks for packages.

Comment: It's 2022 now, and `apt-get install make` still works fine.  `build-essentials` is overkill if all you need is `make`.

Answer (score 244):

Run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Chances are you will need things like `gcc` to actually do the building so you might as well install those as well. The `build-essential` package will install other tools used along with `make`.

Comment: `apt-get -y install make` worked for me in a Dockerfile.

Comment: @Acumenus Whether it worked in a Dockerfile or not, it doesn't currently work in Ubuntu Focal 20.04. The Dockerfile you were using could have been using an image from any version of Ubuntu, so this statement isn't very helpful to others.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu Focal 20.04 natively and `apt-get install make` works just fine.   It's also much nicer in a Dockerfile for just being lighter.

Answer (score 12):

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get -y install make`

(`-y` = answer 'yes' to any prompts)

Check the installed version:

`make -v`

Answer (score 5):

It definitely looks like make is installed on your box. The reply you are getting is actually an error generated by make, complaining that it can't file the Makefile (which would tell it what needs to be done)

Is there any Makefile.pl in the module you are trying to install? If so, try:

```
$ perl Makefile.pl
$ make
```

Answer (score 0):

As [tuxpiper](https://askubuntu.com/a/277295/22949) says, `make` is already installed. What reveals this is the "No targets specified and no makefile found" message, which is produced by `make` itself.<sup>1</sup>

`install-module.pl` is an installation script that is part of Bugzilla. There isn't enough information in the question to be entirely certain that Bugzilla is what's being installed--perhaps there is other software that ships with a script by that name--but the *exact* problem described here is one that people have had while installing Bugzilla.

The problem in this situation is that, behind the scenes, `install-module.pl` uses `cpan` (a Perl package manager) which [doesn't find and use `make` even though it is installed](https://serverfault.com/questions/327620/bugzilla-install-module-pl-cant-find-make-but-its-installed-and-in-my-path).

[**3h4x has given a solution to this.**](https://serverfault.com/a/413283/99345) You can help `cpan` find `make` by running

```bsh
cpan
```

to enter the `cpan` shell, and then running the CPAN commands:

```
o conf make '/usr/bin/make'
o conf commit
```

<sup>*Source: [This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/413283/99345), by [**3h4x**](https://serverfault.com/users/100656/3h4x), to [Bugzilla install-module.pl can't find “make” but it's installed and in my path](https://serverfault.com/questions/327620/bugzilla-install-module-pl-cant-find-make-but-its-installed-and-in-my-path)*</sup>

Note that the *module* being referred to here in the script name is a Perl module, and not any other kind of module such as a kernel module. So if you did not already have `make` and the other necessary development tools, installing `build-essential` should be sufficient to provide them, though it doesn't substitute for configuring `cpan` if necessary.

This question is old and the problem may no longer be common. So I suggest that users installing Bugzilla on newer Ubuntu systems not run those `cpan` commands *until* they have actually observed the problem with `make` not being found even though it's installed.

<sub><sup>1</sup> [**I've posted about this before, apparently.**](https://askubuntu.com/a/277321/22949) I had forgotten about that when I wrote this answer. But it turns out this answer is *a bit* different. For now I'll keep this answer, which addresses the broader issues like what software this applies to, what kind of modules are being referred to, and how readers shouldn't assume they'll have this problem today. But I've made it community-wiki so other people can edit it more easily and so I don't generate reputation from it.</sub>